# Numpy transpose converts entries to strings?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array whose entries are mix of ints and strings. I want to transpose it using numpy, but when I do the ints seem to get turned into strings.

```
In [47]: X

Out[47]: [['a', 1, 2], ['b', 1, 3]]

In [48]: np.transpose(X)

Out[48]:
array([['a', 'b'],
       ['1', '1'],
       ['2', '3']],
      dtype='<U1')
```

I'd really like the output to be:

```
[['a','b'],[1,1],[2,3]]
```

(I can go in and fix it by writing some more code, but that's annoying and not good practice, I think. Although if there is a one or two line fix that would be helpful also. I'm also wondering what numpy is doing to produce this, and how to make it work the way I want it to.)

EDIT:

I notice this happens just when I convert X into a numpy array:

```
In [50]: X = np.array(X)

In [51]: X
Out[51]:
array([['a', '1', '2'],
       ['b', '1', '3']],
      dtype='<U1')
```

EDIT2: Resolved:

```
In [55]: Y = np.asarray(X, dtype = object)

In [56]: Y
Out[56]:
array([['a', 1, 2],
       ['b', 1, 3]], dtype=object)
In [57]: Y.T
Out[57]:
array([['a', 'b'],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 3]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Try with dtype as object

Comment: Actually a numpy array with mixed strings and integers is not good practice.  Switching to `object` dtype works, but looses most of the benefits of arrays (such as fast numeric calculations).

Comment: `np.transpose(X)` is, in effect, `np.array(X).transpose()`.  Most `numpy` functions start off making sure their inputs are arrays.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be when X was converted to a np.array. If you want to convert X to a numpy array with mixed types, use dtype = object: [Numpy dtype for list with mixed data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30740490/numpy-dtype-for-list-with-mixed-data-types)

```
In [55]: Y = np.asarray(X, dtype = object)

In [56]: Y
Out[56]:
array([['a', 1, 2],
       ['b', 1, 3]], dtype=object)
In [57]: Y.T
Out[57]:
array([['a', 'b'],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 3]], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes working with object arrays is less desirable than working with structured arrays.  In case you want to go that route, simple convert you list of lists to a list of tuples and proceed as follows:

```
a = [['a', 1, 2], ['b', 1, 3]]
a = [tuple(i) for i in a]
a
[('a', 1, 2), ('b', 1, 3)]

dt = [('A', '<U5'), ('B', '<i4'), ('C', '<i4')]
b = np.asarray(a, dtype=dt)
array([('a', 1, 2), ('b', 1, 3)], 
      dtype=[('A', '<U5'), ('B', '<i4'), ('C', '<i4')])
```

Then the fields/columns are useful

```
b['B']
array([1, 1])

b['B'].sum()
2
```