# Initialize an empty multidimensional list

Tags: python

I would like to initialize a multidimensional list capable of storing an object for every minute since year 1950-2050.

Something like:

```
minute = [None]*61
hour = [minute]*25
day = [hour]
month = [day]
data = [month]*100
```

So you can do:

```
data[89][1][29][23][55] = 'It was a good minute the one from January 29th in 1989 when it was 23:55'
```

How would be such a multidimensional list be initialized in Python? Would it be an actual different object than the one created with the above code?

Initially the multidimensional list would contain objects None.

Python 2.7

Following answer I tried:

```py
# Data structure
minute = 60
hour = 24
day = 31
month = 12
year = 100
test = [[[[[None for _minute in range(minute)] for _hour in range(hour)] for _day in range(day)] for _month in range(month)] for _year in range(year)]
```

But it seems too much for multidimensional lists, as I get "Killed" when trying to execute this.

Comment: Why do you need to build such a massive dictionary? Is the objective to return a string given the integer inputs, in which case would a function not work?

Comment: It needs to store data for any minute from 1950 to 2050. I have edited the question so it uses word "store" instead of "return".

Comment: Yes, but *why*? What is your *end use case*? I'm guessing it's not going to be printed out, this will cost a lot of ink!

Comment: That's about 52 million minutes. Are you actually going to store an entry for every minute? Why do you need this data structure?

Comment: Fast in-memory store and easy retrieval of the information as show in the example: `data[89][1][29][23][55]`

Comment: I recommend using nested defaultdicts instead, so you don't actually create that many arrays

Comment: Really need to store in python, not consider redis or others?

Comment: I want in memory database, why shall I consider redis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *also* don't recommend this, but you could use a `numpy.chararray` for this:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.chararray((100, 12, 31, 24, 60, 60), itemsize=100)

arr[52, 7, 12, 12, 44, 54] = 'year 1950+52, 7th month, 12th day, 12th hour, 44th minute, 54th second'
```

I'm not exactly sure what your desired structure is, but the string I inserted into the array should explain the structure I proposed, and you can change it however you need. Note that `itemsize` limits how many characters you can put in at any index.

Again, with a caveat that this is not necessarily the most efficient thing in the world to do, but if you wish to store lists of ints and/or floats in that array (as per your comment), one way to do it would be to convert that list to strings, and then when retrieving it, re-transform back to a list:

```
data_to_insert = [1,2,3,4.5]
# store as string
arr[52, 7, 12, 12, 44, 54] = ','.join(map(str, data_to_insert))
# retrieve
arr[52, 7, 12, 12, 44, 54].decode('utf-8').split(',')
```

This should be pretty fast

Comment: The object to be stored is another list with 4 floats and 1 integer. I never used numpy so I am not sure if it can handle it better than a multidimensional list. It must be fast to retrieve any given minute.

Comment: There could be also None instead of the described list.

Comment: I am exploring this which might fit better https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30740490/numpy-dtype-for-list-with-mixed-data-types Not sure if dtype will allow to fullfil this particular case

Answer (score 2):

*Though i won't recommend it,*
A multi dimentional empty list can be created by using list comprehension:

```
> >>> a = 4 #Width of elements
> >>> b = 6 #Width of main list container
>>>>> c = 4
>>>>> d = 3
> >>> l = [[[[0 for k in range(d) ] for z in range(c)] for x in range(a)] for y in range(b)]
> >>> [[[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]], [[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]], [[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]], [[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]], [[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]], [[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]]]
```

> Keep replacing 0 with list comprehensions to add more dimentions.

Comment: It would eat your memory and since linked list takes linear time, it'll take too much computation as well. Though it is what you asked for!

Comment: I thought it would be extremely fast, as you are indexing everything. Anyway python can not generate such big multidimensional list -see my edited question-

Comment: Did you get any errors while generating that list? If yes, try the other answer's solution. Use numpy arrays instead of normal lists. They are fast and well designed for this kind of tasks.

Comment: Can a numpy array store lists of 4 floats and 1 float? Objects to be stored have this form: [67.4, 65.3, 68.8, 69.5, 10000] or None object

Comment: Easily, It's used in machine learning and they use like crazy complex arrays.

Comment: Thanks I will then further explore numpy

Comment: Then accept the answer which you think suits you more.